# Apache Flink calculate quantiles on streaming data [in scala)

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to calculate quantiles on streaming data in Flink using Scala. My question is similar to but simpler than this one [flink calculate median on stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451604/flink-calculate-median-on-stream). I think this can be done by defining a custom aggregation function but i was looking for some Scala examples. I have looked at the examples in https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises but did not quite find what i was looking for. I have the sum calculated, mean calculated and i would like to calculate the 95th percentile.

```
val nwStream = env
  // TestData topic is our Kafka topic
  .addSource(kafkaConsumer)
  // configure timestamp and watermark assigner
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TestDataTSAssigner)
  // group by stats by
  .keyBy(_.sSomeId)
  // sliding window is 5 minutes long and slides every 1 minute
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5), Time.minutes(1))
  .apply { (key: String, window: TimeWindow, events: Iterable[TestData],
            out: Collector[(String, Long, Long, Double, Double)]) =>
  out.collect((key, window.getEnd, events.size,
    events.map(_.stat1).sum/events.size,
    events.map(_.stat2).sum/events.size)
}
```

I would like to be able to compute the 95th percentile in a similar way in the collect function. Isnt there some way i could do this using a FlatMap? It would be awesome if we could just say

```
events.map(_.stat1).quantile(0.95)
```

but i understand there is no built in quantile function today.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A thoroughly accurate quantile/percentile calculation across the entire stream requires keeping the entire stream in state, which is not at all scalable. I would recommend instead using something like the [t-digest sketch](https://github.com/tdunning/t-digest) to do an estimation.

I don't know of anyone who has done this with Flink, but it should be reasonably straightforward.