# How do I perform a simple median algorithm for a Flink DataStream (preferably in Java and Flink 1.14)?

Tags: java, apache-flink, median

I have a datastream in Flink of messages that look like: `(Name, Place, Number, Time)`

I want to keep track of the median number per key.

To make matters a little more complicated....

Lets say I have the messages:
`(Jonah, Mars, 1, 1:00)`
`(Jonah, Mars, 2, 1:01)`
`(Jonah, Moon, 3, 1:02)`
`(Jonah, Earth, 4, 1:03)`

I want to take a median using only the most recent messages per place ie, using just:
`(Jonah, Mars, 2, 1:01)`
`(Jonah, Moon, 3, 1:02)`
`(Jonah, Earth, 4, 1:03)`

Here the answer is `3`

`(Jonah, Mars, 1, 1:00)` was not included because `(Jonah, Mars, 1, 1:01)` is more recent

My assumption is that it will look like:

```
inputStream
            .keyBy(message -> message.name)
            .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(30,1))
            .<MEDIAN FUNCTION>
```

I am guessing the answer would leverage `MapState`, though I am no sure how to use windowed `MapState`...

Note: Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451604/flink-calculate-median-on-stream). The advice here was not to do it.... unfortunately though, I need a median :(

Comment: When do you want to produce results? E.g., on a per-key basis, after every event for that key? Or at some regular interval (i.e., once a minute)? Or whenever the median for some key changes?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a `KeyedProcessFunction`, where the keys are names. Then in keyed state you can keep `MapState` that maps from locations to the most recent event for that location (for that name).

Then when you want to produce a result, you'll have to walk the map.

This is somewhat painful, but I don't have a better idea. If you are performance sensitive, need to use this at large scale, and don't need an exact answer, you could use a t-digest sketch instead.